# Video.js and loading a segment in handleSegmentResponse

Tags: javascript, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am working on a slightly specific project that requires me to load chunks in video.js whose source is not a CDN. Specifically, I have stored chunks in a map that were transferred over P2P.
I already managed to stop the xhr request for a chunk and I already have the needed chunk ready. What I cant figure out is how to "load" the chunk inside the player.
I've been fiddling around with the handleSegmentResponse method but I can't seem to make it work.
Everything up the the point of actually having the segment or chunk locally is taken care of. How do I pass it along to the loader?
Note: The chunk is in the form of an ArrayBuffer i.e in the same format as all response data for chunks.

Thank you and sorry for the lack of code. I also could be using the wrong method. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
if (segment.key) {
    segment.encryptedBytes = new Uint8Array(chunkMap.get(currentChunkName).arrayBuffer);
} else {
    segment.bytes = new Uint8Array(chunkMap.get(currentChunkName).arrayBuffer);
}
```